# Router is slowing internet connection from 17 Mbps to 3 Mbps

Tags: router, traffic-shaping

The office is equipped with a Edgewater EdgeMarc 4500 router (Software Version 11.6.18 -- Mon Mar 25 14:01:38 PDT 2013).  I did a test and determined that the router is slowing down the internet from 17 Mbps to 3 Mbps:

[image: speed test]

...and as I was writing this question, I did some more digging and found this:

[image: traffic shapping]
[image]

Turning off traffic shaping fixed the problem.  Should I leave it on but change the vaules?  What should the values be?

This is a small office with 3 VOIP phones and a max of 3 people, usually 1, working.

Comment: Please change the title, a Edge Router is a different product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you have selected for Primary WAN downstream and upstream bandwidth are just about exactly the speeds you are getting with the speed tests. These should instead be set to approximately your actual bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why someone would implement that kind of traffic shaping for a network so small, and with such silly values at that.

Turn it off, but make note of its potential existence since you're utilizing VoIP.  QoS may be required later on as your office grows to accommodate both VoIP and general connectivity, but this is not that.